# C# RegEx behaviour different in .NET 5 than other versions

Tags: .net, regex

Can anyone explain the following to me? I'm using a regex expression to validate hex colors (that can also include a alpha component). The code I'm using is as follows;

```
new Regex("^(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3,4}){1,2}$").IsMatch(str)
```

I've tested my expression on various regex test sites, and .NET Fiddle (see below) and it works

https://dotnetfiddle.net/W33vbL

and yet, running server-side on our app (.NET Core 5) it fails. If I attach to the process, I see the following error;

[image: error image]

If I stick the expression in the watch window, I see the following;
[image]

The same expression works fine on .NET 3.1 and 6, but not .NET 5.

Comment: Just to make sure: try `.IsMatch(Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-fA-F0-9]+", ""))`

Comment: It replaces nothing, see [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/OJ9HuyTApK)

Comment: Can you clarify what the question here really is, so that you're not getting swamped with "here, this is how you fix it" comments and answers? Are you really asking why you overly complex regex for testing color is not working, or are you asking what a better expression would be? I read it as "why doesn't this work", but you're going to get a lot of "here, use this instead" type of answers until you make sure people understand what you're *really* asking about.

Comment: @Nick It _appears_ to replace nothing. It wouldn't surprise me if there are hidden characters in that string. Try to log the length of the string.

Comment: Well, I did not expect to see anything as I expected invisible / non-printable chars mess with matching. When the code and regex are fine, the problem is always in the data.

Comment: Please try this: `str.ToCharArray().Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X2")).ToArray()` and then post the results here.

Comment: Hi Lasse. My question is it should work. Maybe the regex is overly complicated (I don't think so), but I'm not interested in the regex, I'm interested in why a valid expression is not being resolved. It should be, I've shown that with .NET Fiddle, I'm asking why C# regex appears to behave differently in different environments

Comment: Thanks Ivar. Length of the string is 6. No extra characters

Comment: Please edit that part into the question. I don't know why it wouldn't work in .NET 5.

Comment: I just tested in LINQPad, where I can select to run either on .NET 3.1, 5 or 6. It works in 3.1 and 6, but not in 5. I would think this is a bug, perhaps you should file an issue with Microsoft on GitHub?

Comment: Lasse, I don't have a using statment for linq, so the select doesn't work (would take me a while to re-compile/deploy). However, to double check the chars, see [here] (https://www.screencast.com/t/TglyZaLUn)

Comment: OK, thanks Lasse. That would make sense. (I just tested in LINQPad, where I can select to run either on .NET 3.1, 5 or 6. It works in 3.1 and 6, but not in 5. I would think this is a bug, perhaps you should file an issue with Microsoft on GitHub?)

Comment: There's no need for the char array, I basically just typed in `new Regex("^(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3,4}){1,2}$").IsMatch("8DB3E2")` and it returns `true` in .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6, but `false` in .NET 5. And yes, I did type, I did not copy and paste so I am sure I have no hidden or invisible or otherwise strange characters in either the pattern or the input.

Comment: It seems to be some backtracking that is missing, if I make the `{3,4}` non-greedy by adding a question mark after it, the pattern works in .NET 5 as well.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, that's helpful. I'll post an issue on github. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As per the helpful comments, this looks like a bug with .NET 5; see the following

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/56721

Comment: Please add a link to the issue after you've posted it, this way future visitors, if they ever trip this bug before it's fixed (assuming it will be) can find the issue as well.